# Remove xmlns attribute from xml

Tags: c#, xml, c#-4.0, xmldocument, xmlnode

In below Xml, I tried to delete the xmlns attribute but, its unable to populate under,
xmlNode.Attributes still appear under OuterXml and final XmlDocument.

```
... 
<z:Datac knid="2" xmlns="http://services/api/"></z:Datac>
...
<z:Datac knid="3" xmlns="http://services/api/"></z:Datac>
....
<z:Datac knid="5" xmlns="http://services/api/"></z:Datac>
....
```

How to remove xmlns attribute for each z:Datac element?

```
foreach (var item in nodes)
{
    var xmlnsAttribute = (item.Attributes has "xmlns" attribute)

    if (xmlnsAttribute != null)
    {
        Remove xmlNode...  //not able to reach here as not able to find xmlns.
    }
}
```

I don't have xml.linq

Comment: what have you tried? and are you *tied* to `XmlDocument`? in `XDocument`,  `el.Attribute("xmlns")?.Remove();` seems to work... (obviously in real code you'd want to test the xmlns against the element's .Name.Namespace, and only remove if different)

Comment: don't have, linq.xml. its plain - xmldocument/xmlNode.

Comment: the link above is using with xElement from linq.xml.. here it does'nt have.

Comment: yeah, I'm undoing that close-as-duplicate; that's a completely different and incompatible API

Comment: Where are you getting this XML from? It looks very suspicious; colons are used to separate XML namespaces from tags, and the `xmlns` attribute is used to distinguish namespaces. But these are all wrong in your XML fragment, the `z` namespace is never defined and the `xmlns` attribute does not define a namespace. Either this XML does not use namespaces, is badly corrupted, or you're not showing us the actual XML.

Comment: Yes,its like this as received stream and loaded with. related namespace on document.

Answer (score 2):

I *guess* you'd want something like:

```cs
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("my.xml");
foreach(var node in doc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes)
{
    var el = node as XmlElement;
    if (el != null)
    {
        if (el.HasAttribute("xmlns"))
        {
            var ns = el.GetAttribute("xmlns");
            if (ns != null && ns != el.NamespaceURI)
            {
                el.RemoveAttribute("xmlns");
            }
        }
    }
}
doc.Save("new.xml");
```

Obviously you'd probably want to make it query, or issue an all-elements query, in complex scenarios.

Comment: Problem is, ` if (el.HasAttribute("xmlns"))` does not get true but, el.OuterXml has xmlns and namespaceURI exists.

Comment: @dsi I tested it... it worked fine here; if you're seeing it failing in a specific scenario, it would help to post that exact scenario with representative code and xml; if you're saying that it isn't applying to the document/root element - fine: just fix that!